# Writing to a multi dimensional array with split

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-3.x

I am trying to use python to parse a text file (stored in the var trackList) with times and titles in them it looks like this

```
00:04:45 example text
00:08:53 more example text
12:59:59 the last bit of example text
```

My regular expression (rem) works, I am also able to split the string (i) into two parts correctly (as in I separate times and text) but I am unable to then add the arrays (using .extend) that the split returns to a large array I created earlier (sLines).

```
f=open(trackList)
count=0
sLines=[[0 for x in range(0)] for y in range(34)]   
line=[]

for i in f:
    count+=1
    line.append(i)
    rem=re.match("\A\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\W",line[count-1])
    if rem:
        sLines[count-1].extend(line[count-1].split(' ',1))
    else:
        print("error on line: "+count)
```

That code should go through each line in the file trackList, test to see if the line is as expected, if so separate the time from the text and save the result of that as an array inside an array at the index of one less than the current line number, if not print an error pointing me to the line

I use `array[count-1]` as python arrays are zero indexed and file lines are not.

I use `.extend()` as I want both elements of the smaller array added to the larger array in the same iteration of the parent for loop.

Comment: What is your question? Is it: "Fix my code!...?" Because that isn't a question.

Comment: `[0 for x in range(0)]` is a very complicated way of writing `[]`. And what's the relevance of 34?

Comment: What is your desired end result, and why is it not something like `[("00:04:45", "example text"), ("00:08:53", "more example text"), ("12:59:59", "the last bit of example text")]`?

Comment: @phihag 34 is the number of lines in the file trackList, in my code its actually a variable that is storing the result of a line counting operation on the file trackList, but that also works

Comment: @tripleee sorry i wasnt clear about that, your guess is correct i would like my result to look like `[("00:04:45", "example text"), ("00:08:53", "more example text"), ("12:59:59", "the last bit of example text")]`

Comment: @charlieg my question is why isnt extend appending an array to the specified index of another pre initalised array

Comment: @hamsolo474 Ok, I would suggest putting that as the title, the first sentence, or last sentence of your question. Did the answer below answer your question? If so, don't forget to mark it as correct and upvote anything you found helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have some pretty confusing code there.

For instance doing:

```
[0 for x in range(0)]
```

Is a really fancy way of initializing an empty list:

```
>>> [] == [0 for x in range(0)]
True
```

Also, how do you know to get a matrix that is 34 lines long?  You're also confusing yourself with calling your line 'i' in your for loop, usually that would be reserved as a short hand syntax for index, which you'd expect to be a numerical value.  Appending i to line and then re-referencing it as line[count-1] is redundant when you already have your line variable (i).

Your overall code can be simplified to something like this:

```
# load the file and extract the lines
f = open(trackList)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

# create the expression (more optimized for loops)
expr   = re.compile('^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s*(.*)$')
sLines = []

# loop the lines collecting both the index (i) and the line (line)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    result = expr.match(line)

    # validate the line
    if ( not result ):
        print("error on line: " + str(i+1))
        # add an invalid list to the matrix
        sLines.append([])  # or whatever you want as your invalid line
        continue

    # add the list to the matrix
    sLines.append(result.groups())
```

Comment: `'00:00:00 this is a test'.split(' ')[1]` is different to 
`'00:00:00 this is a test'.split(' ',1)` and only the latter produces the desired effect `['00:00:00', 'this is a test']`


also `expr = re.match('^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s*(.*)$',"00:04:45 example text")` doesn't work.


The for loop is better, but it is still not producing the desired effect, i will research a bit more you have given me some ideas, thanks

Comment: Ah, my bad - you are correct on the split - I missread.  The regex should work tho.  What doesn't work for you?  I just copied and pasted to an interpreter and it worked just fine: >>> result = re.match('^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s*(.*)$',"00:04:45 example text")
>>> result.groups()
('00:04:45', 'example text')

Comment: I don't know what happened when I tried your regex the first time, but it didn't work, but now it works, I must of mistyped something. Also after further research I find your regex better as it replaces the need for a split function.